# Query a table based on values from within that table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-insert, where-clause

We have a WordPress site that contains a Q&A plugin, that needs to be moved to a different hosting. The Q&A posts only make up for a fraction of the total Posts table, so I want to filter them out using a SQL query.

I want to select everything in the DB, through PhpMyAdmin, for the rows that match one of the following criteria:

1. `post_type = "answer"`
2. `post_type = "question"`
3. post_type contains revision, preceded by the ID of either one of the previous criteria. For example: `21-revision-v1` or `10903-revision-v1` Where I want to select those posts of which the first numerical part matches the ID of posts selected in the previous 2 requirements.

I am a complete novice to SQL so I started with some googling, and found the concept of Temporary Tables. Which lead me to create this bit of code:

```
SELECT *  INTO #QA 
FROM `wp_posts` WHERE 
`post_type` = "answer" OR
`post_type` = "question"
```

However I get the following error:

> #1064 - Er is iets fout in de gebruikte syntax bij 'FROM `wp_posts` WHERE
> `post_type` = "answer" OR
> `post_type` = "question" LIMI' in regel 2

Which translates to "There is somthing wrong with the syntax near"....

Is what I am attempting even feasible?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Phpmyadmin @jarlh

Comment: @Abra to be honest I have no clue at all. I was asked to take a look into this because others couldn't figure it out. Basically I have a grasp of which buttons I need to push to make certain things happen, but that is where my knowledge of all this PhpMyAdmin, and SQL included, ends.

Comment: @Abra okay good to know. I know how this site works, which you ought to know by my reputation count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax that you are using is most commonly associated with SQL Server.  MySQL uses the (more common) `create table as` syntax.  And, it allows specifically for temporary tables in the syntax.

So, the equivalent in MySQL is [`CREATE TABLE AS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE QA AS
    SELECT p.*  
    FROM wp_posts p
    WHERE post_type IN ('answer', 'question');
```

Note that a temporary tables is a very specific type of table that exists only in the current "session" -- say, your current connection to the database.  It is not visible to other users and it will disappear when you reconnect to the database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that a temporary table is what I need in order to make a selection that includes my third criteria. I inserted a bit more explanation on that criteria including examples.

Comment: @Luuklag . . .  I see no reason to use a temporary table for this purpose, except as a demonstration of creating tables.  It is simple enough to filter the posts when querying the table directly.

Comment: Well that is my VBA background kicking in then. Where you always have to write these kind of things into a table/variable first. My level of understanding of SQL is clearly sub-par to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does not support the `select ... into ...` syntax to write to a table, as [pinpointed in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html).

Instead you can use `insert ... select`:

```
insert into `#qa`
select *
from wp_posts
where post_type in ('question', 'answer')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `SELECT *  INTO...` syntax is used to create a new table.
If this is what you want then the syntax for MySql is:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename AS
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` 
WHERE `post_type` = 'answer' OR `post_type` = 'question'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I omit the first line I get the selection that I expect (129 rows). If I include the first line I get an empty table, and a notification: "MySWL returned an empty resultset (o rows)."

Comment: @Luuklag How do you use this query? This is not a query that returns rows. It creates a new table. This is the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html

Comment: that is what I expected. Running it a second time made the list of table actually refresh, and now it shows two such tables. Thanks!