# Using Substring_Index with data from a second table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, where-clause

## As a follow up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64135354/query-a-table-based-on-values-from-within-that-table/64135592?noredirect=1#comment113416164_64135592):

I want to select everything in the `wp_posts` table that matches:

1. `post_type = "answer"`
2. `post_type = "question"`
3. post_type contains revision, preceded by the ID of either one of the previous criteria. For example: `21-revision-v1` or `10903-revision-v1` Where I want to select those posts of which the first numerical part matches the ID of posts selected in the previous 2 requirements.

I now constructed a new table `ap_qa` which holds all the ID's from posts matching either criteria 1 or 2 above.

Now to select the cases that match criteria 3 I thought of using `Substring_Index()` as that allows for matches within a string.

My current code is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `wp_posts` p 
WHERE p.post_type IN ('answer', 'question') OR
Substring_Index(p.post_Type,'-revision',1) IN QA.ID
```

The first rule following where is to satisfy criteria 1 and 2, the last row is meant to satisfy criteria 3. However my syntax is invalid, as is returned.

The error message reads (in Dutch):

> #1064 - Er is iets fout in de gebruikte syntax bij 'QA.ID' in regel 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I now constructed a new table ap_qa which holds all the ID's from posts matching either criteria 1 or 2 above.

You don't at all need a temp table for this. You can get the result that you want directly from the original table in a single query:

```
select *
from wp_posts wp
where post_type in ('answer', 'question') and exists (
    select 1
    from wp_posts wp1
    where 
        wp1.post_type in ('answer', 'question') 
        or wp1.id = substring_index(wp.post_type, '-revision', 1)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a subquery that returns the ids of the table `ap_qa`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `wp_posts` p 
WHERE p.post_type IN ('answer', 'question') 
   OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.post_Type,'-revision',1) IN (SELECT ID FROM ap_qa)
```

Or without the table `ap_qa`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `wp_posts` p 
WHERE p.post_type IN ('answer', 'question') 
   OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.post_Type,'-revision',1) IN (
         SELECT ID FROM `wp_posts` 
         WHERE p.post_type IN ('answer', 'question')
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your systqax is wrong as you error message indicates
Use something like zhis

```
SELECT * 
FROM `wp_posts` p 
WHERE p.post_type IN ('answer', 'question') 
OR
 QA.ID LIKE CONCAT(Substring_Index(p.post_Type,'-revision',1) ,'%')
LIMIT 0, 25
```